# Unable to use pen pressure in Blender using iPad

Tags: customization, grease-pencil, 2d

I’ve been having trouble enabling the pen pressure when using Blender grease pencil using my iPad connected to my PC using the EasyCanvas Pro app.

The brush strokes I make stay the same size and opacity no matter how much pressure I use and even when I change the size and strength of the pen. I set my preferences to use the Windows Ink for the tablet API and have the pen pressure sensitivity icons for the size and strength enabled. I tried the other options for the tablet API and restarted the program each time but I still have the same issue.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Update**
Here’s a snapshot of the issue I’m having:
[image]

**Update**
I found that if I switch from wireframe to viewport shading, my pen strokes don’t really show. But when I draw with my finger, the stroke matches the opacity and size I set
[image]

And when I switch to wireframe it reverts back:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

chiyopet,

If you are using Grease pencil, there could be a couple things that are causing the issue.

Lets get the basics out of the way:

If you new to Blender...Welcome! if you not and having trouble, a really simple things would download a fresh copy of Blender from https://www.blender.org

on the slashscreen click "2D Animation"

[image]

start drawing with you iPad.....(I have no idea what application your using to draw with ....so that could be getting in the way...but let see if we can help you. If this works.....wonderful! if not, keep reading.

Then follow these directions:

1. Start Blender
2. Click "File" in top left corner and select "New" > "2D Animation" from the dropdown list

This will open the 2D Animation workspace and with a grease pencil object selected and in the "Draw" mode with the Draw Tool Selected. It will also have a material for you selected to draw with.

All this means that Blender is ready for you to Draw in 3D.

Try to Draw....if you still do not see anything.

A) Check you are in Draw Mode:
Look in top right corner of 3D Viewport:
[image]

B) Check that you have the large enough brush size and strength of brush
and most importantly that you have "Use Pressure" icon checked:
Here is a nice graphic with a copy of setting for you to use:

C) Check 3D Viewport is in the correct Viewport Shader. If you look on the top right side you will most likely want to be in "Material Preview" or "Rendered"

[image]

Here is the blender Documentation on the what the different Viewport Shaders
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html

This video does a good job of at least giving a quick overview of viewport shading and what is does in a very quick way.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=knO-oz6_ffI

Comment: Thanks for your response and helpful graphics! I included a snapshot of what I have right now. I followed the steps but I’m still experiencing the issue. You’ll see that brush size and strength are maxed out but my strokes’ size and opacity is still the same

Comment: I have updated by answer after seeing an image of your blender screen. Please notice your The top right corner of your 3D Viewport is set to wireframe not " Material Preview" or "Rendered". I also added a link to the documention so you and anyone can learn some more amazing things blender can do!!! Happy Blendering!!

Comment: I tried setting it to material preview and rendered but the brush size and opacity is still the same. I included a new picture on an odd thing I found, but it does show that the set brush size and strength work but only when I draw with my finger. Thank you for including a link to the doc, I’ll be sure to take a look!

Comment: Ok, you could use fingers on your iPad, then we know Blender working. 
 For the moment, just for testing, do not use EasyCanvas Pro app. Just use "Sidecar" connecting a wire between your computer and iPad or wireless if there are on the same network". This test will find out if it in EasyCanvas Pro app is issue.

1) One the Mac, top Left corner click on  (apple icon) and chose "System Preferences..." Then click on "Sidecar" and then click button under "Connect to" to select device.  Just using "Sidecar" and Mac ....you should be able see strokes.....also make sure pen charged :-)

Comment: Oh would that work with Windows PC? I don’t have a Mac.

Comment: Sidecar only works with a Mac ( it is built into the OS). I think I have go as far as I can go.  I am sorry I could not help you :-(  I hope this does not dull your view of Blender it is an amazing piece of software. Do not give up. This is just a little issue. if you keep searching you will find the answer. Life always finds a way.  It could be an update that is needed for video card or the software. It might take a day of two to find the answer....but don't give up! treat other and yourself well and have fun Learning!! Smartdog

Comment: Thanks so much for your help smartdog! I’ll be sure to keep this post updated on what I find. But this has definitely not dulled my experience so far with Blender! I am excited to see what things I could learn and create from this program :D Thank you for the warm welcome!

Comment: I updated the bottom of the post to include a YouTube video I found about viewport shading. When in “wire frame” mode , Blender is always going to show you just the basics lines and points. You want, for now, to creating strokes in “material preview” mode till you solve the issue. Here is the video to help you understand more about viewport shading ... there are other videos..this one is short snd to the point <https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=knO-oz6_ffI>

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sidecar with my iPad Air. And I can confirm the OP's issues still exist. I think it's an iPad thingy. In other words, iPad + Apple pencil does not work the same as Wacom when it's used for grease pencil.

Solution to OP, disable pen pressure strength (it's the small icon on the right side of the strength settings). You won't get pressure strength but the colours will be all 100% solid.